# O método SaveAs da classe Workbook falhou

Tags: vbscript

```
Const xlShiftDown = -4121

'Arquivo de entrada

strInput = WScript.Arguments(0)

'Arquivo excel

strOutput = WScript.Arguments(1)

'Arquivo excel

strFormato = WScript.Arguments(2)


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE

objExcel.Visible = FALSE


Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strInput)

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Columns("BL:BM").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("AP:BA").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("AM:AN").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("AK:AK").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("O:AI").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("B:F").Delete

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strOutput, strFormato

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
```

Chamada do método abaixo:

```
cscript S:\j\users\sclytr\filtroTabelaExtratoHotel.vbs "S:\j\users\sclytr\tabelas_extrato_hotel\5441e896290e48a7b16677ac4770b50a.xls" "S:\j\users\sclytr\tabelas_texto\tabelas_extrato_hotel.txt"  20
```

Mensagem de erro abaixo:

> S:\j\users\sclytr\filtroTabelaExtratoHotel.vbs(34, 1) Microsoft Excel:
>   O método SaveAs da classe Workbook falhou

Comment: difícil saber sem a captura do erro, mas tem a possibilidade de ser relacionado a permissão, já que é uma operação de escrita. Você tentou executar o comando como Administrador?

Comment: Boa tarde Leandro. Tentei agora e ocorreu o mesmo erro. O objetivo final é converter um xls para um txt. mas sempre chego a este erro. O que estranhamente não ocorria ontem.

Comment: Bom, se o código funcionava ontem, não foi alterado, hoje apresenta um erro... O que mudou de ontem para hoje? O arquivo de entrada, o de saída que já existe e não pode ser sobrescrito? Pense no que está diferente hoje...

Comment: De fato. Os procedimentos foram, tirar o FALSE do objExcel.DisplayAlerts, assim ele me mostrou um alerta que em que dizia não conseguir acessar o arquivo de saída. Resolvido isso, está funcionando perfeitamente.